# In Gerrit, can I someway have all the commits that have not been reviewed/approved from the repo?

Tags: distributed, gerrit

I am working in a distributed team and it is not possible to have a review and approval of each commit quickly as the team members who are supposed to review are located overseas.

The team working at my end, push the code to Gerrit for review. Let us say user1 pushed 5 commits and user2 pushed 10 commits.

My question is me being user3, can I get all these 15 commits without pulling each commit individually using the commit id??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the "Search" field.

For example, to find all open changes from user1 or user2:

```
(owner:user1 OR owner:user2) AND status:open
```

Take a look [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html) to learn more about the search feature.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a command I could use to pull all of the above 15 unreviewed commits to my system?

Comment: You need to make a script to find the changes using REST (running, for example, curl --request GET --netrc https://<gerrit>/a/changes/?q=\(owner:user1+OR+owner:user2\)+AND+status:open), process the result (using, for example, jq) and pull the commits.